# ASP.NET Identity - user logged out after couple of minutes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I use following code for ASP.NET Identity:

```
var options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    CookieName = "ScanTest",
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
    LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
};

app.UseCookieAuthentication(options);
```

When I publish my application to Azure, it logs out users after couple of time of inactivity. It is really hard to figure out what is the problem because on dev machine it does not log me out.

Any help?

Comment: are you using oauth2 authentication ?

Comment: can i know that which authentication you are using ?

Comment: OWIN Authentication

Comment: Do you have <machineKey >  in your webconfig?

Comment: @Hadee it looks like it was reason for auto-logout. You should put it as answer so I can choose yours

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36440655/3743442