# Take me log in long time doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I have authentification for my site builded with SimpleMembershipProvider.
I log in with such code:

```
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe);
```

RememberMe is true.
And it worked fine for debugging(when I runned my site on IIS on my computer), but when I published site on the hosting I've faced log out every minute (when I try to move to action which require to be authorize - I am moved to login page).

I checked created cookie on my browser and it looks fine(it will be expired after 2 days after creation).

I use SimpleMembershipProvider as my MembershipProvider. This is how I declare it in web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=SimpleMembershipProvider+set+timeout

Comment: @AshleyMedway, sorry forget to add this code. Yes, I've also specified that in my config.

Comment: Have you checked `<machineKey>` in your project `webconfig` ?

Comment: @RustamSalahutdinov Are you sure that your webapp not restarted between requests? You can add some log into `Application_Start` method to see that.

Comment: @Hadee. No, I don't have any one in my config. What is it? I create new instance of WebSite in Visual Studio with example code. And there is no <machineKey> here too.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36440655/3743442

Answer (score 0):

The problem was restarting of IIS on my hosting. My site use too big amount of RAM, so after several calls my site's pool was automatically restarted.
This is way me authentification doesn't work.